# WPF: combining TextBox input and validation rules

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, user-input

I am learning about properly implementing input validation. I have reviewed dozens of similar questions about different aspects of it, but for my case, combining all these different solutions is confusing. In the essence, I have a bunch of textboxes in my application that need to be validated by these requirements:

1. All textboxes must allow numeric values. Some textboxes must allow positive/negative Doubles, some only positive/negative Integers, some only positive variants of each. Meaning that user can enter `0-9`, `.` and `-`, but only once. Regex filter `("[^0-9.-]+")` can filter such inputs, but it doesn't prevent the user from entering something like `9.1.2` or `-5-5`, so it doesn't work.
2. Some textboxes must allow entering multiple valid numbers separated by a space, like `1 5.61 -7.2`. So the user can enter a space symbol now as well, but only after a valid number, and only once (so that they don't place five spaces between numbers). Meaning that if the user types one space, he should not be allowed to type another in sequence.
3. If the user enters an invalid value (or multiple values) that cannot be parsed into integer/double, the textbox should fix it automatically. For example, if user enters `123.`, it should automatically be corrected into `123`. If the user enters nothing, or just one symbol, like `-`, textbox should automatically restore previous valid value.

So right now, the textbox (for single values, I haven't solved multiple values yet) is defined as:

```
<TextBox x:Name="numericValuesTextBox" PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextBoxNumeric">                             
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="UserValues" Converter="{StaticResource StringToDoublesArrayConverter}">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:DoublePositiveOrNegative/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

PreviewTextBoxNumeric - this bit handles that only valid characters can be entered:

```
Private Sub PreviewTextBoxNumeric(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TextCompositionEventArgs)
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[^0-9.-]+")
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text)
End Sub
```

However, like I said, it still doesn't prevent the user from entering values that later cannot be converted to an integer or double, causing an exception. PreviewTextInput event only checks a single character only, so it is not very useful.

And the DoublePositiveOrNegative rule looks like this:

```
Public Class DoublePositiveOrNegative
    Inherits ValidationRule

    Public Overrides Function Validate(value As Object, cultureInfo As Globalization.CultureInfo) As ValidationResult
        Dim result As Double
        If Double.TryParse(value, result) Then
            Return ValidationResult.ValidResult
        Else
            Return New ValidationResult(False, $"Invalid number")
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

However, all this does right now is set the border of the textbox in red - it doesn't restore the original value. And I can't see how to store that value here, since this class is instantized only during the binding attempt.

I am unsure on how to combine all these requirements into neat, compact and reusable solution that I could use anywhere on my application. I do not know how to make input check rule (currently that Regex bit) that checks not only if valid character is being entered, but also if it can be logically entered to make a valid number (not allowing several commas, etc.). And also, how to restore the original value if the input is still invalid (ideally, this shouldn't be needed if the first check works right).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you handling `PreviewTextInput` instead of validating the value in the validation rule?

Comment: @mm8 - because I can't figure out how to prevent user from entering invalid characters in the validation rule. The validation rule only seems to provide error after the invalid entry, but doesn't prevent it in the first place - or at least I don't know how to make it do it.

Comment: No, it *validates* the input. So what behaviour do you want want?

Comment: @mm8 - I want to prevent invalid entry when the user presses a wrong key on the keyboard. For example, if user enters "-1.5", it should be allowed. But if after that he tries to enter another minus sign, that sign should not appear in the textbox at all. Or, for example, if he is separating multiple values in the textbox by a space, he should only be allowed to enter one space symbol - second one should not appear.

Comment: So you are handling all this in `PreviewTextInput`?

Comment: @mm8 Currently, yes, as I don't see any better way. One of the problems with `PreviewTextInput` is that it doesn't recognize spaces... I am open to suggestions here.

Comment: So you don't really need/use the validation rule after all?

Comment: @mm8 When I was writing the question, I thought that validation rule could be used to prevent invalid entry (as opposed to displaying an error after the entry), but it appears now that perhaps this should be done without validation rules. Currently I don't use them. I am handling everything via `PreviewTextInput` and `LostFocus` event handlers. Still, it is a very nasty solution. I am sure there must be a better way with WPF.

Comment: Validating data and preventing input are two different things. Validation should be handled in the view model and the latter in the control.

Comment: @mm8 Okay, I see. Thank you for the clarification. So how do I prevent the user from inputing something like "1.5.1" or "--1" or "5   5" (too many spaces)?

Comment: You will have to validate the input (text) on each keystroke I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but what is the best way to do it in WPF? Certainly not through event handlers like I'm doing it now, right?

Comment: Yes, implement some kind of numeric text box. It can be implemented using event handlers.